# What is the syntax for adding characters in unicode form to HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, unicode

I know that it's possible to add symbols using unicode; I've seen it done before, but don't remember how. I need to make the list items to be the *raquo* character from this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references. It's unicode point is *U+00BB (187)*.

Here's a simple fiddle that gives a scenario of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3wh6997q/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a> Item 1</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a> Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a> Item 3</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

ul > li > a:before
{
    content: ">>"; /* Actually I want the content to be the raquo character */
}
```

Comment: What about `content: "»";` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
ul > li > a:before
{
    content: "\00BB"; 
}
```

You needed the hexadecimal value.

There's a list for resources here: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm